# Deploy java web application to Tomcat with Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, tomcat, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to deploy a java web application to Tomcat using Visual Studio Code and I'm having some issues that I'd like to share.

After installing the extension [Tomcat for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adashen.vscode-tomcat), I've tried to deploy a Maven Java Web project. To do so, I've clicked over project's folder and selected "Run on Tomcat Server" option. The result is an error with this message: `The folder is not a valid web app to run on Tomcat Server.`

Then, I've realized that maybe I should create a war file before running it on Tomcat. Therefore, I've executed `mvn clean package` command and afterwards execute "Run on Tomcat Server" option over the war file. Doing this the project has been deployed correctly.

However, compared to Eclipse's way to work with Tomcat, it seems to me a bit tedious. Particularly if I'm working with static files, like css or js, because every time I modify a file I should execute `mvn clean package` and "Run on Tomcat Server". Whereas, in Eclipse, these files are deployed automatically on Tomcat without restarting.

I wonder if there is another way to work with VS Code and Tomcat for Java.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing: putting the output folder in an auto-deploy folder would work, but it has been some time since I worked with Tomcat. In the documentation I read "Deployment of exploded web applications which are copied into the Host appBase." and "Re-loading of a web application if the /WEB-INF/web.xml file (or any other resource defined as a WatchedResource) is updated. " under "Deploying on a running Tomcat server"; this may be what you are after.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. AFAIK Visual Studio Code executes building whenever I change a file of `src/main/java` or `src/main/resources`. So, as you say, I could change the ouput folder to copy the modified files to the exploded war. However, this might not work for `src/main/webapp` folder's file because VSCode doesn't trigger the building for these files. Let me know if I've misunderstood something.

Comment: You can use the Visual Studio Code Live Server extension for this...

Answer (score 1):

If you use Spring, there is an easy way.

The [Spring Initializr](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-spring-initializr) extension comes with an embedded Tomcat installation, and hot reloading works out of the box.

Rely on the following guide to install it:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-spring-boot

Comment: Note: I do not care if this answer is downvoted by Spring haters. I know it can help Spring developers, hence I will leave it here at the cost of my SO reputation.